# i install phpmyadmin on my ubuntu but its not working

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-10.04

i install phpmyadmin on my ubuntu 10.4 but its can't login

this is the  content of ***/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php*** file

if we enter password ***#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server***

if we not enter password ***Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)***

can you help me

```
/**
 * Debian local configuration file
 *
 * This file overrides the settings made by phpMyAdmin interactive setup
 * utility.
 *
 * For example configuration see /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/config.default.php.gz
 *
 * NOTE: do not add security sensitive data to this file (like passwords)
 * unless you really know what you're doing. If you do, any user that can
 * run PHP or CGI on your webserver will be able to read them. If you still
 * want to do this, make sure to properly secure the access to this file
 * (also on the filesystem level).
 */

/**
 * Server(s) configuration
 */
$i = 0;
// The $cfg['Servers'] array starts with $cfg['Servers'][1].  Do not use $cfg['Servers'][0].
// You can disable a server config entry by setting host to ''.
$i++;

/**
 * Read configuration from dbconfig-common
 * You can regenerate it using: dpkg-reconfigure -plow phpmyadmin
 */
if (is_readable('/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php')) {
    require('/etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php');
}

/* Configure according to dbconfig-common if enabled /
if (!empty($dbname)) {
    / Authentication type */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    /* Server parameters */
    if (empty($dbserver)) $dbserver = 'localhost';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = $dbserver;

if (!empty($dbport)) {
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $dbport;
}
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
/* Optional: User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = $dbuser;


$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = $dbpass;
    /* Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = $dbname;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';

/* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
 * after taking note of the associated security risks. */


// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

/* Advance to next server for rest of config */
$i++;


}

/* Authentication type */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it /
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
/ Optional: User for advanced features /
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
/ Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
/* Uncomment the following to enable logging in to passwordless accounts,
 * after taking note of the associated security risks. */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

Comment: What error message do you receive?

Comment: Please be more specific about how it's not working. Is the PMA web console not loading? Can it not connect to mysql?

Comment: sometimes changing host from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' would do the trick, but it all depends on the error you get.

Comment: if we enter password #2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Comment: if we not enter password Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a blank password uncomment:

```
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

It is safe if you are inside an isolated development VM, otherwise set a password.

Comment: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/lamp-linux-apache-mysql-php-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

i follow this link so now a days its work fine

Answer (score 3):

I've been having the same problem, but I think I may have sorted it out..

Solution:
Assuming you used the setup.php file to setup phpMyAdmin, once you've finished configuring your mysql server and you've saved the changes, copy the config.inc.php file, auto-created in the config/ folder, out into the phpMyAdmin folder.. Make sure it's write-protected and delete the config/ folder.. Then refresh your browser..

Worked for me.. Hope it works for you too.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks but i already solved the problem by my own by removing all and installing fresh copy